# Erasing love from the world

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, culture

**TL:DR**

> love sucks and causes humans to blindly look for a perfect match which eventually fails because no one is perfect for one another, relationship are built not gifted from God

Evolutionary speaking love is damaging sex and making couples weaker and frail.

The only purpose of sex is reproducing and bounding in order to gain trust, affection and boosting the immune system etcetera.

Couples need to be strong in order to grow and educate healthy children which will in turn protect their families when they reach adulthood. This was the standard of humanity for almost it's entire evolution.

Families where not built on the idea of  "oh this guy must be my soul mate cause I feel it deep inside of me" and then fall apart when the couple realizes that they might not be soul mates, leaving children to grow  in a collapsed or collapsing family which eventually makes them into weaker adults mentally and physically.

Instead families where built based on survival alone. People didn't date 20 to 50 people during their youth in search for that special perfect partner in hope that they are soul mates destined to be together and chosen by the universe.

This promiscuity has caused sexual dissease which were once a rarity to be some of the most common illnesses in the entire world, HIV for example grows at a rate of 1.7 millions a year even though this virus is incredibly hard to spread given modern protections and the fact that it only spreads through blood and sexual mucose alone are not enough. But this doesn't stop people from ruining lives.

And mates where chosen just like friends are chosen to this day, based entirely on vicinity.

Today humans are the most promiscuous they have ever been, which logically would mean it's a good thing, more people are born and the species goes on. But humans unlike reptiles need to be educated on how to live and having a random  children with a guy you don't even remember the name is not a good strategy, while it's true that this behavior brings more people to the world, it's also true that it weakens humanity.

As times goes on dumber and more uneducated humans are born each day, people educated by Hollywood and cartoons instead of a family who thrive in the world only through luck and coincidence.

Divorce rates are growing everyday because people forgot that relationship are not destined but are a destination which requires growth, we grow personally but we forgot how to grow as couples.

However this behavior and mentality remained pure and uninfected when it comes to friendship, people are still willing to build friendship based on respect, trust and sincere generosity because we gain mental health from each other and we accept our reciprocity in this leach behavior where we consume each other's time in order to be happier and stronger.

This means that humans still know how not to be brainwashed by the concept of love.

**Question:**
I, personally, the villain of my own story desire to forcefully delete the concept of love from the planet as to purge humanity off the weak. Just like how wolves purge their prey off the weaker individuals and making them stronger through natural selection.

But I also want to be as peaceful as possible, answers where death is minimal or avoided completely are preferred.

The resources needed for this maleficious plan are handed to me by the magic power of **PLOT**  but everything must fall in the realm of credibility.

**Edit** 
By erasing love I strictly mean the idea of love in relationships in a way that people don't chase love like sharks chasing fish. People just choose their partners based on survival instinct alone and in regards to reproduction and the success of their children.

Comment: (1) Do you want to delete the *concept* of love, or do you want to delete *love* iself? They are not synonymous. (2) There is so much more to love than sexual desire. Patriotism, artistic, technical and scientific achievements, charity are all driven in a very large part by love. (3) Sexual desire is not necessarily love. That's why Amor and Venus (or Eros and Aphrodite) are separate divinities. (4) If you think that the modern world is promiscuous you should pay closer attention to the classical antiquity and the middle ages. (True, the incidence of STDs was very much lower in those times.)

Comment: So Orwellian. "One was ‘making a baby’, and the other was ‘our duty to the Party’." or still one of my favorite 1984's quotes: "‘When you make love you’re using up energy; and afterwards you feel happy and don’t give a damn for anything. They can’t bear you to feel like that. They want you to be bursting with energy all the time. All this marching up and down and cheering and waving flags is simply sex gone sour. If you’re happy inside yourself, why should you get excited about Big Brother and the Three-Year Plans and the Two Minutes Hate and all the rest of their bloody rot?’"

Comment: Love is an artificial byproduct construct to explain  oxytocin. "Oxytocin is a powerful hormone that acts as a neurotransmitter in the brain. It plays an important role in reproduction, initiating contractions before birth as well as milk release. And it is thought to be involved in broader social cognition and behavior, potentially ranging from mother-infant bonding and romantic connection to group-related attitudes and prejudice. The hormone is produced in the hypothalamus and released into the bloodstream by the pituitary gland.  https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/basics/oxytocin

Comment: serial monogomy is the norm across human societies, including hunter gather societies,  so part of your premise is wrong. also you seem to be confusing love and attraction. The average intelligence of each generation is higher not lower. Also divorce rates correlate very well with social changes like wars, changes in the law, (such as no fault divorce laws), and women's rights.

Comment: 'By erasing love I strictly mean the idea of love in relationships in a way that people don't chase love like sharks chasing fish.' What you have described is 'lust', not necessarily 'love'. Different hormones completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really, really debated giving an answer to this question, because it may be one you do not want. You see, the problem with this answer is the **Law of Unintended Consequences**.

As I posted in my comment on your question, there is no such thing as **love**. It is a completely artificial construct, a buzz word that is applied to what are essentially many very distinct concepts and entities. It is of the utmost importance to clearly identify exactly what you want to eliminate, without resorting to calling it 'love'.

What I can gather from the **TL** part of your **TL:DR**, you are asking specifically about a concept sometimes referred to as **romantic love**, the term that describes couples coming together to form a pair-bond relationship. Current research seems to implicate the chemical oxytocin as the 'love drug' that actually invokes the sensations and feelings in humans that we call 'being in love'. I will bring my post up here.

> "Oxytocin is a powerful hormone that acts as a neurotransmitter in the
>   brain. It plays an important role in reproduction, initiating
>   contractions before birth as well as milk release. And it is thought
>   to be involved in broader social cognition and behavior, potentially
>   ranging from mother-infant bonding and romantic connection to
>   group-related attitudes and prejudice. The hormone is produced in the
>   hypothalamus and released into the bloodstream by the pituitary gland.

http://psychologytoday.com/us/basics/oxytocin

In humans, there are specific genes that lead to the production of oxytocin in the body, so the immediate answer to your question is to somehow eradicate these genes in the human gene pool. You mentioned you were not averse to using magic, so this would be the target of your magic. I might suggest that you use gene-altering viruses to introduce the genetic modification in your population. It's not quite totally legitimate, but it would suffice with a bit of handwaving.

By eliminating these genes, you would produce a population that is not at all concerned with romantic attachments or able to demonstrate or feel 'romantic love'.

The **Law of Unintended Consequences** part, is that by doing so, the normal process of birth is severely disrupted. The female would have e very difficult time with contractions, lactation, and a few other complications, not to mention the lack of bonding with the baby. Your society would in all probability end up having the children raised in nurseries, perhaps by unmodified mother surrogates. It might also, incidentally, eliminate some small part of the pleasurable sensation from orgasm.

We do in fact have such people in our population. They are a sub-group of high-functioning autistics. This subgroup is lacking the gene that produced oxytocin, and thus they have very low levels of it. It is posited that their lack of neurotypical social functioning is a result of this genetic modification.

> There is growing recognition of the importance of improving the social
>   impairment in autism, for example difficulties in sharing feelings,
>   demonstrating eye contact, or understanding emotions in others.
>   Increasingly research has shown that oxytocin may improve some of
>   these difficulties in people with autism. It appears that the oxytocin
>   system, including genes, may be abnormal in at least a select group of
>   people with autism.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/spectrum-theory/201306/the-trust-hormone-how-oxytocin-can-help-treat-autism

Basically, by eliminating the human capacity to experience romantic love, you have produced a society of [Aspergers](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/basics/aspergers-syndrome). The irony is that you are actually creating **neuro*UN*typical** humans with a modification that medical science is looking for ways to make more **neurotypical**.

***EDIT***

Here is the clinical research evidence for the above. I did not cite it previously, because it is, well, medical and not physics.

> While therapeutic application of oxytocin for ASD is in its early
>   stages, we have concluded that oxytocin would be a promising
>   therapeutic substance via a thorough literature review focusing on the
>   following: the relationship between oxytocin and sociality; single
>   nucleotide polymorphisms as a biological marker of ASD; and validity
>   verification of oxytocin treatment in humans.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4688331/

Comment: Yes I am talking about an entire society of Sheldons.

Comment: As a person with a diagnosis of Asperger's syndrome I find it disturbing that you are lumping together "eliminating the human capacity to experience romantic love" and "a society of Aspergers". The article you have quoted says nothing to suggest this: it is a highly erroneous conclusion you have come to yourself. I am certainly not incapable of love, and have never encountered anything to suggest that a person with Asperger's syndrome would be so. I fear it is a small step from "incapable of love" to categorising people with Asperger's as some inhuman "other".

Comment: I have a small sample to judge from (1). The only asperger person I know is the smartest guy I know and he has quite strange relationships with women seeing the girls that interest him more as "mothers" or "sisters"

Comment: @C. R. Yasuo  It is what it is. The main criteria for Asperger's syndrome is a marked impairment of social functions. https://www.iancommunity.org/cs/about_asds/about_asds_dsm_iv_criteria_for_aspergers_syndrome  Absent this, it is not Asperger's syndrome. Since 'love' is an artificial construct, it is very easy for anyone to define love any way they perceive it, and then say 'I am in love'. That is the entire premise of my response. For it to be quantifiable, it has to be more than just a conditioned state of mind, it has to be biological. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4688331/

Comment: @C. R. Yasuo I'm sure you can understand that many diseases have varying degrees of gravity, which can be commonly seen in cases of autism and Down syndrome, Justin clearly is referring to a more extreme case. Additionally, like the answer also said, love isn't something concrete, or that you can easily measure, and at no point he said that one who is affected by this condition can feel no love whatsoever. This isn't that different from saying psychopaths are monsters and autistic people have no social skills, those refer to the worst cases (although being generalized sometimes, sadly).

Comment: @ProjectApex A clarification - autism is not a disease, it is a condition. There is no illness. Sheldon would have been perfectly content living in a world of Sheldons. In which case being what we consider neurotypical would be seen to be an aberration, an exceptionality. Primates evolved the oxytocin gene because it was beneficial - primate infants were born premature (not able to locomote) because of our brain size (imagine giving birth to a six-month-old able to crawl), so it was imperative that the baby not be abandoned at birth. Pair bonding was a necessity for large brains small vaginas.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second my apologies, I wrote disease instead of condition by mistake. I understood your point, I just meant that you'd likely be referring to a more extreme case of the condition , with lower oxytocin production. Not that it would be considered weird in a society in which the condition was common. Some African tribes with sickle cell anemia are a perfect example: having being an advantage in their survival, the condition is not considered as odd by them, for it is usually present in most of the tribe .

Comment: @ProjectApex :)

Comment: @ProjectApex I do understand that different people on the autistic spectrum are very different. That's part of why I made my original comment. But the statement that Justin Thyme made was "By eliminating [the capacity for romantic love], you have produced a society of Aspergers", which in my view is definitely the kind of sweeping generalisation that you have described as "sad". And no part of the evidence quoted suggests that even some people with ASD don't experience romantic love, only that oxytocin may be effective in therapy for some -- hence saying so was a big jump to a conclusion.